# Can I set a conditional breakpoint without specifying a specific location?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

**Similar questions:** [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488155/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-when-variable-is-getting-a-specific-value-in-net), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635609/set-visual-studio-conditional-breakpoint-on-local-variable-value). But this is not what I am looking for.

**Similar questions, but said options are diabled:** [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160045/break-when-a-value-changes-using-the-visual-studio-debugger), [Four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224031/how-get-a-breakpoint-on-variable-write-in-visual-studio), [Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871328/visual-studio-how-do-i-have-the-debugger-stop-when-a-member-variable-is-modifie).

**Situation:** I want to identify the line where the value of the variable `ApplianceState` changes to the value `normal`. `ApplianceState` is an `enum` type and can have one of 4 different values. The project I am working on is quite huge and looking for it line-by-line could take days.

**Question:** Is there a way I can set a watch so that visual studio breaks at the line where the value of `ApplianceState` changes to `normal`?

I know I can set a conditional breakpoint, but that would mean I have to set a break point on certain line, and I don't want to do that.

Also, I have enabled `native code` debugging and the menu item `New Data Breakpoint`, in menu `Debug` -> `New Breakpoint`, is disabled (greyed out). So, I can't select it.

Comment: to set a data-breakpoint (eg. answer to #3), you need to be stopped in the debugger already, you cannot do it while the program is running.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito The debugger is stopped. I have tried that while the program is running, paused for debugging, compile time and during editing. It is never enabled.

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc, Which kind of app did you really debug? It just supports the VC++/C app: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6097301-support-data-breakpoints-for-c, and then you could add it just the breakpoint was hit. For the C# app or others, it doesn't support it. You could create a default Win32 console app, check the result.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT This is humongous application. The final code is deployed on to household electronic devices. It is not just a VC++ project. It is a C project run in Visual Studio. This C code is run in a simulation (which is in C#, I think), and then burnt on to the chipsets of devices.

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc, If a simple C or VC++ app developed in the VS IDE works well, but this app doesn't work, I feel that it doesn't support feature "Set a Data Breakpoint (Native Only)", the breakpoint was hit during debugging, am I right?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Normal breakpoints are hit. Conditional breakpoints are hit. I just can't "set a data breakpoint". I don't think this big project is "native only", as I think it runs on the "simulation".

Comment: I agree with you, ctrl-shift-esc. I think this specific project doesn't support this feature.